# Flatten hierarchical list of types with selectmany linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

Wanted to see if anyone could offer any suggestions on how to condense the list aggregation while using selectmany. Any recommendations are welcome.

I want a flat list of all elements including the Program. Creating a list I can search through.

Thanks!

```
Program prog = new Program
            {
                Mods = new List<Mods>
                {
                    new Mods
                    {
                        Acts = new List<Acts>
                        {
                            new Acts
                            {
                            },
                            new Acts
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Mods
                    {
                        Acts = new List<Acts>
                        {
                            new Acts
                            {
                            },
                            new Acts
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

//everything is an Element.            
var pes = new List<Element> {prog};
pes.AddRange(prog.Mods.ToList<Element>());
pes.AddRange(prog.Mods.SelectMany(m => m.Acts).ToList<Element>());
```

Comment: What does "condense the list aggregation mean"?  For that matter, what does "list aggregation" mean?

Comment: I want to know if anyone has a more concise way of flattening this hierarchy to a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var pes =
    Enumerable.Repeat<Element>(prog, 1)
        .Concat(prog.Mods)
        .Concat(prog.Mods.SelectMany(m => m.Acts))
        .ToList();
```

This assumes `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (C# 4.0 or greater).  If it's not, you can do this instead:

```
var pes =
    Enumerable.Repeat<Element>(prog, 1)
        .Concat(prog.Mods.Cast<Element>())
        .Concat(prog.Mods.SelectMany(m => (Element)m.Acts))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly. that's what I'm talking about.